# Working with CKEditor 3's templates: Issues with preserving HTML markup

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor as part of the WYGWAM plugin for ExpressionEngine, but at the core my issue is a CKEditor issue.

I have some custom HTML markup for certain UI elements and thus far have had no problems using the templates_files and [CKEditor 3 Templates](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates) to use them.

However, for some reason, not all the markup of each HTML template is being preserved.  In the following case with applying expand/collapse accordion list, the first "toggler" isn't preserved when going to the next < li > item.

**The code:**

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates( 'default',
{
    imagesPath : CKEDITOR.getUrl( CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath( '../../../../wygwam_assets' ) + 'template-thumbs/' ),

// Template definitions.
templates :
    [

        /* toggler */
        {
            title: 'Expand & Collapse List',
            image: 'testing.png',
            description: 'Create a collapsed list of expandable items.  When each title is clicked, the content below will animate open and reveal the full content.',
            html:
                '<div class="toggle_wrap"><ul>' +
                '<li><div class="toggler">ITEM_TITLE</div><div class="togglee">ITEM_CONTENT</div></li>' +

                '</ul></div>'
        }
    ]
```

});

Oddly enough, when pressing enter at the end of the last line for the < li >, the next item on the list is added with the following output:

```
    <li>
        <div class="togglee">
        </div>
    </li>
```

The **togglee** div is there!  But why oh why not the **toggler**?!

Answer (score 0):

See if setting allowedContent to true in your config for CKEditor makes a difference. This is used to strip style and class attributes etc. so basically strip out content that is not allowed by default.

e.g.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```